# How can I get the conversation between a user and bot in dialogflow cx?

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I know that it is possible to save the logs by enabling cloud logging. But I just want to download the conversations like as it has in the conversation history. I tried using method: projects.conversation.get but it didn't work because it returns 404 not found. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that is not possible in Dialogflow CX. The endpoint you tried is for Dialogflow ES.

You will need to enable the bigquery export.

Answer (score 0):

[BigQuery Export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ha3Fm.png)
You Can export your conversation in BigQuery
Create a Table in BigQuery

```
CREATE TABLE <your_dataset_name>.dialogflow_bigquery_export_data(
  project_id STRING,
  agent_id STRING,
  conversation_name STRING,
  turn_position INTEGER,
  request_time TIMESTAMP,
  language_code STRING,
  request JSON,
  response JSON,
  partial_responses JSON,
  derived_data JSON,
  conversation_signals JSON
);
```

https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/export-bq